# how to convert character to integer in C or C++

Tags: c++, c

How can I assign variable x of type int the value 3 from the char variable ch = '3'??.

```
    char ch = '3';
    int x;
    // assign 3 to x using ch.
```

Comment: `int x = ch - '0';` should work fine.

Answer (score -2):

`x=ch-'0';`

Use the above code you will get your desired answer!

Comment: Bit of a detailed explanation how that works exactly,  and why would be nice.